# DirectShow graph not using HW acceleration for all filters when using EVR with custom presenter

Tags: c#, render, directshow, renderer, hardware-acceleration

I'm new to DirectShow and MediaFoundation so please be patient if the obvious is right in front of me. My preferred language is C# and I am building a video player using direct show and I have a graph consisting of these filters (I'm describing the video path only):

```
LAV source fiter -> LAV video decoder -> Enhanced Video Renderer
```

Everything works beautifully except for the fact that when changing from one video to the next (playing a playlist here) I get a black frame in between the videos causing the screen to flicker. The performance however when using this graph is excellent, CPU stays mostly at 0% except when transitioning between videos.

Now, in order to get rid of the black frame I tried using the EVR with a custom presenter. I tried both the custom evr presenter sample from the v6.1 SDK (`<RootDrive>\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SDKs\ Windows\v6.1\Samples\ Multimedia\MediaFoundation\EVRPresenter`) as well as a .NET implementation from codeproject - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/419286/EVR-Presenter-in-pure-Csharp-with-Direct-D-Video-R

Both work just fine, however the CPU consumption goes to about 30-40% for a 1080p video on the machine I'm testing on.Taking out the 3D rendering by commenting out the code is bringing no improvement in terms of CPU consumption so that seems to be properly HW accelerated which makes me think the other components in the graph - namely the video decoder and perhaps the EVR mixer are not using the IDirect3DDeviceManager9 device manager returned by the custom presenter from the GetService method (this actually gets called by the way).

So, question is, what do I have to do in order to have HW acceleration being used by all components and achieve the same level of performance I get when using the EVR with the default presenter?

Many thanks in advance,

Ionut

Comment: Anyone, any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd guess that the higher CPU consumption in your custom presenter is caused by the render loop (thread?) that makes empty cycles.